# What is the cheapest way for 2 Australians to travel from New Orleans (or Miami) to Cuba?

Tags: visas, budget, health, cuba, new-orleans

We are two Australians visiting our daughter in new Orleans.  We would like to visit Cuba for a holiday.

What is the cheapest way for us to get there, and is there a time limit for how long we could stay?

Do we need a visa and any vaccinations?

Comment: What is `cheap` to you? Moreover you are asking various question into one. It's better to split them up. ;)

Comment: Stack Exchange is like Stack Overflow, in that it needs questions that have specific answers that can potentially help other people faced with a similar problem. We only take on recommendation questions if there are peculiar needs or the usual ways to get answers can be shown not to work. You can try asking a separate question for each specific problem you are facing and how you've tried but failed to find the answer. Or you can try a regular forum like Lonely Planet Thorn Tree, Quora, etc that don't have the "anal" rules inherited from Stack Overflow (-;